# What does "of such" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, british-english

My mother language is not English, so please give me a clear explanation of what does "of such" mean in this sentence? I could not find an equivalent in my language. The sentence is:

> encourage humans to overeat and sells them pharmaceuticals to alleviate the negative consequences **of such a gluttonous diet**.

Comment: It's not "of such". It's "consequences of [such a gluttonous] diet".

Comment: If your native language is not English you should be posting on English Language Learners, not here.

Comment: @David: Nonsense. Most of the posts here on ELU are from non-native speakers, mostly English students having trouble with the usual rotten teachers and textbooks.

Comment: @JohnLawler — So they are posting to the wrong list, and anyone who answers rather than redirecting them is encouraging them. I quote "ELU…is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists and serious English language enthusiasts".

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you give us the whole sentence, please? Also, why did you use the british-english tag? This doesn't appear to be limited to British English...

Answer (score 1):

“Of such” is not one word. It is not part of the same construction either.

The general sentence:

> Encourage humans to overeat and sells them pharmaceuticals to alleviate the negative consequences of (Object).

Here, the object is (such a gluttonous diet). This is referring to the diet that was just mentioned in the text. You can replace the (Object) with something else as well.

Comment: Exactly. As we say in syntax, _of such_ is not a constituent of the sentence. It turns out that grammar only applies to constituents, not to random series of words.

Answer (score 0):

'Of such a [thing]' means 'of a thing of the particular type just described'. The consequences of such a gluttonous diet are the consequences of the type of diet just described.

[Such](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/such)